# Getting Audio Driver Path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the Driver path of media devices through PowerShell, but my code prints a blank. Anyone know how to get te driver path?

```
$mediaDevices = Get-PnpDevice -Class MEDIA

foreach($device in $mediaDevices){
    Write-Host "Driver Version: $($device.Driver)" 
    Write-Host "" 
}
```

Comment: Why would there be a driver property?

Comment: [The `Win32_PnPEntity` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity) doesn't have a `Driver` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, which filters by `DeviceClass` property of `Win32_PnPSignedDriver` and then selects `DriverVersion` field:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Where { $_.DeviceClass -eq "MEDIA" } |  Select DeviceName,DriverVersion,DeviceClass
```

See [Win32_PnPSignedDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394354(v=vs.85)).